Flutter Riverpod unable to rebuild widget with ref.watch
My app structure is Categories -> Meals -> MealDetails -> EditMeal
My code:
MealNotifier:
class MealsNotifier extends Notifier<List<Meal>> {
  @override
  List<Meal> build() {
    return userMeals;
  }
  updateList(List<Meal> meals) {
    state = List.from(meals);
  }
}

final mealsProvider = NotifierProvider<MealsNotifier, List<Meal>>(() {
  return MealsNotifier();
});

Categories:
class CategoriesScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const CategoriesScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<CategoriesScreen> createState() => _CategoriesScreenState();
}

class _CategoriesScreenState extends ConsumerState<CategoriesScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _selectCategory(BuildContext context, Category category) {
    final meals = ref.watch(mealsProvider);
    final categorizedMeals =
        meals.where((meal) => meal.categories.contains(category.id)).toList();

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx) => MealsScreen(
          title: category.title,
          meals: categorizedMeals,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animationController,
      child: GridView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20,
        ),
        children: [
          for (final category in availableCategories)
            CategoryGridItem(
                category: category,
                onSelectCategory: () {
                  _selectCategory(context, category);
                })
        ],
      ),
      builder: (context, child) => SlideTransition(
        position: Tween(begin: const Offset(0, 1), end: const Offset(0, 0))
            .animate(CurvedAnimation(
                parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeInOut)),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}

MealsScreen:
class MealsScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MealsScreen(
      {super.key,
      required this.title,
      required this.meals,
      this.favoritesScreen = false,
      this.noAppBar = false});

  final String title;
  final List<Meal> meals;
  final bool noAppBar;
  final bool favoritesScreen;

  @override
  ConsumerState<MealsScreen> createState() {
    return _MealsScreenState();
  }
}

class _MealsScreenState extends ConsumerState<MealsScreen> {
  
  List<Meal> filteredMeals = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    filteredMeals = widget.meals;
  }

  void _selectMeal(BuildContext context, Meal meal) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx) => MealDetailsScreen(
          meal: meal,
        ),
      ),
    ).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        if (widget.favoritesScreen) {
          filteredMeals = ref.watch(favoriteMealsProvider);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    void openFilters() async {
      await Navigator.of(context).push<Map<Filter, bool>>(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => const FiltersScreen()),
      );
      setState(() {
        filteredMeals =
            ref.watch(filtersProvider.notifier).filteredMeals(widget.meals);
      });
    }

    PreferredSizeWidget? appBar = AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
      actions: [
        IconButton(onPressed: openFilters, icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_alt))
      ],
    );

    Widget content = ListView.builder(
      itemCount: filteredMeals.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => MealItem(
        meal: filteredMeals[index],
        onSelectMeal: () {
          _selectMeal(context, filteredMeals[index]);
        },
      ),
    );

    if (widget.noAppBar) {
      appBar = null;
    }

    if (filteredMeals.isEmpty) {
      content = Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Nothing here",
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .headlineLarge!
                  .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            Text(
              "Try adding your favorite recipes!",
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .bodyLarge!
                  .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: content,
    );
  }
}

MealDetailsScreen:
class MealDetailsScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MealDetailsScreen({super.key, required this.meal});

  final Meal meal;

  @override
  ConsumerState<MealDetailsScreen> createState() => _MealDetailsScreenState();
}

class _MealDetailsScreenState extends ConsumerState<MealDetailsScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  late Meal meal;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    meal = widget.meal;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final favoriteMeals = ref.watch(favoriteMealsProvider);

    final bool isFavorite = favoriteMeals.contains(meal);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
        ),
        title: Text(meal.title),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => CreateMealScreen(meal: meal),
                  ),
                );
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.edit)),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              final wasAdded = ref
                  .read(favoriteMealsProvider.notifier)
                  .toggleMealFavoriteStatus(meal);
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text(wasAdded ? "Meal added" : "Meal Removed"),
                ),
              );
            },
            icon: AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              transitionBuilder: (child, animation) {
                return SlideTransition(
                  position:
                      Tween(begin: const Offset(0, 1), end: const Offset(0, 0))
                          .animate(CurvedAnimation(
                              parent: animation, curve: Curves.easeInOut)),
                  child: child,
                );
              },
              child: Icon(
                isFavorite ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border,
                color: Colors.amber,
                size: 25,
                key: ValueKey(isFavorite),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Hero(tag: meal.id, child: Image.file(meal.imageFile)),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            child: AppBar(
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: const [
                  Tab(
                    text: "Ingredients",
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: "Instructions",
                  )
                ],
                controller: _tabController,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(height: 16),
                      for (final ingredient in meal.ingredients)
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                          child: Text(
                            ingredient,
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .bodyMedium!
                                .copyWith(
                                    color: Theme.of(context)
                                        .colorScheme
                                        .onBackground),
                          ),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(height: 16),
                      for (final step in meal.steps)
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 8, vertical: 8),
                          child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  "Step ${meal.steps.indexOf(step) + 1}",
                                  style: Theme.of(context)
                                      .textTheme
                                      .bodyLarge!
                                      .copyWith(color: Colors.grey),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  step,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                  style: Theme.of(context)
                                      .textTheme
                                      .bodyMedium!
                                      .copyWith(
                                          color: Theme.of(context)
                                              .colorScheme
                                              .onBackground),
                                )
                              ]),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

CreateMealScreen:
class CreateMealScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const CreateMealScreen({super.key, this.meal});

  final Meal? meal;

  @override
  ConsumerState<CreateMealScreen> createState() {
    return _CreateMealScreenState();
  }
}

class _CreateMealScreenState extends ConsumerState<CreateMealScreen> {
  String pageTitle = "Create Meal";
  late final String id;
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  File? _image;
  List<Category> categories = [];
  List<String> ingredients = [];
  List<String> instructions = [];
  Duration duration = const Duration(minutes: 0);
  bool isGlutenFree = false;
  bool isLactoseFree = false;
  bool isVegetarian = false;
  bool isVegan = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.meal != null) {
      pageTitle = "Edit Meal";
      id = widget.meal!.id;
      _titleController.text = widget.meal!.title;
      _image = widget.meal!.imageFile;
      categories = List.generate(
          widget.meal!.categories.length,
          (index) => availableCategories.firstWhere(
              (category) => category.id == widget.meal!.categories[index]));
      ingredients = widget.meal!.ingredients;
      instructions = widget.meal!.steps;
      duration = Duration(minutes: widget.meal!.duration);
      isGlutenFree = widget.meal!.filters[Filter.glutenFree]!;
      isLactoseFree = widget.meal!.filters[Filter.lactoseFree]!;
      isVegetarian = widget.meal!.filters[Filter.vegetarian]!;
      isVegan = widget.meal!.filters[Filter.vegan]!;
    } else {
      categories.add(
          availableCategories.firstWhere((category) => category.id == "c11"));
      id = uuid.v4();
    }
  }

  void _onGlutenFreeChanged(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      isGlutenFree = value;
    });
  }

  void _onLactoseFreeChanged(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      isLactoseFree = value;
    });
  }

  void _onVegetarianChanged(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      isVegetarian = value;
    });
  }

  void _onVeganChanged(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      isVegan = value;
    });
  }

  void _setImage(File image) {
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(pageTitle)),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 16),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              Text(
                "Title",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .titleLarge!
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              TextField(
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .bodyMedium!
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                controller: _titleController,
                maxLength: 50,
              ),
              CreateMealImage(
                image: _image,
                onImageSelected: _setImage,
              ),
              Text(
                "Ingredients",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .titleLarge!
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              CreateMealIngredients(ingredients: ingredients),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              Text(
                "Instructions",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .titleLarge!
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              CreateMealInstructions(instructions: instructions),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              Text(
                "Categories",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .titleLarge!
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 12),
              CreateMealCategories(categories: categories),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Duration",
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .titleLarge!
                        .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      Duration? dur = await showDurationPicker(
                          context: context, initialTime: duration);
                      setState(() {
                        if (dur != null) {
                          duration = dur;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      duration.inMinutes == 0
                          ? "Set Time"
                          : "${duration.inMinutes} min",
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .bodyMedium!
                          .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              CreateMealFilters(
                  isGlutenFree: isGlutenFree,
                  isLactoseFree: isLactoseFree,
                  isVegan: isVegan,
                  isVegetarian: isVegetarian,
                  onGlutenFreeChanged: _onGlutenFreeChanged,
                  onLactoseFreeChanged: _onLactoseFreeChanged,
                  onVegetarianChanged: _onVegetarianChanged,
                  onVeganChanged: _onVeganChanged),
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_titleController.text.isNotEmpty &&
                        categories.isNotEmpty &&
                        ingredients.isNotEmpty &&
                        instructions.isNotEmpty &&
                        duration.inMinutes != 0) {
                      setState(() {
                        int index = userMeals.length;
                        Meal meal = Meal(
                          id: id,
                          categories: [for (var item in categories) item.id],
                          title: _titleController.text,
                          imageFile: _image,
                          ingredients: ingredients,
                          steps: instructions,
                          duration: duration.inMinutes,
                          filters: {
                            Filter.glutenFree: isGlutenFree,
                            Filter.lactoseFree: isLactoseFree,
                            Filter.vegetarian: isVegetarian,
                            Filter.vegan: isVegan,
                          },
                        );
                        if (widget.meal != null) {
                          index = userMeals.indexOf(widget.meal!);
                          userMeals.remove(widget.meal);
                        }
                        userMeals.insert(
                          index,
                          meal,
                        );
                        // userMeals = List.from(userMeals);
                        ref.read(mealsProvider.notifier).updateList(userMeals);
                      });
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    } else {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(
                          content: Text(
                              'Missing Information. Please fill out all fields.'),
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  style: const ButtonStyle(),
                  child: const Text("Done"),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Now I know that's a lot of code, but it's for more context. The question in brief is:
void _selectCategory(BuildContext context, Category category) {
final meals = ref.watch(mealsProvider);
final categorizedMeals =
    meals.where((meal) => meal.categories.contains(category.id)).toList();

Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (ctx) => MealsScreen(
      title: category.title,
      meals: categorizedMeals,
    ),
  ),
);
}

This method in the code above is responsible retrieving the meals list from the provider, filtering them by category, and pushing the MealsScreen (which is a listview of the meals).
If you tap a meal from the MealsScreen it takes you to the MealDetailsScreen. On the MealDetailsScreen you have an edit button that takes you to the CreateMeal (EditMeal). This is where you make changes to the meal, add it to the userMeals list and set the provider's state to userMeals.
Based on my previous usage of the ref.watch method, this should rebuild the categories widget, but it doesn't. My suspicion is that the problem lies in pushing other widgets (screens / pages) on top it prevents the rebuild, but I don't know how to workaround it.

you placement of ref.watch is wrong. ref.watch should be called inside build() fn so that it can cause widget to rebuild but in your case you have placed it inside a fn _selectCategory() which is called on event like click. right?. As the ref.watch became out of scope for build, it is not able to rebuild the widget. If on btn click or any other event you want to get data use ref.read for that and you can call setState() after playing with data to rebuild widget and reflect ui changes. As i can see you are also using Navigator.push after getting  the data after the watch, normally it should have thrown error as ref.watch() rebuild the widget, but when using Navigator.push also you change the widget tree. which should cause error to throw as the widget was already building and you try to rebuild the widget again. so always use Future.delayed() or WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){}) for navigating to other screen when rebuilding the widget or you can await for Navigation.push() and after that call setState()
Try to do this
void _selectCategory(BuildContext context, Category category) {
final meals = ref.read(mealsProvider);
final categorizedMeals =
    meals.where((meal) => meal.categories.contains(category.id)).toList();
 setState(() {});

WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
   Navigator.push(
   context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (ctx) => MealsScreen(
        title: category.title,
        meals: categorizedMeals,
      ),
    ),
  );
 });
}

or you can try this:
void _selectCategory(BuildContext context, Category category) async {
final meals = ref.read(mealsProvider);
final categorizedMeals =
    meals.where((meal) => meal.categories.contains(category.id)).toList();
 
await Navigator.push(
   context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (ctx) => MealsScreen(
        title: category.title,
        meals: categorizedMeals,
      ),
    ),
  );

setState(() {});

Both option have its usage , 1st one will relect changes and then navigate you to other screen and the second one will navigate you to other screen and when you go back to previous then it will relect changes

What I'm trying to do is to rebuild all the widgets that have been pushed on the screen, starting from Category until MealDetails. If I make changes to the meal in MealDetails and modify the mealProvider, what I'm expecting is for all these widgets to be rebuilt with the new data from the list. Even when using ref.watch inside the build method and passing it _selectCategory method, the result is the same
